# Putting DataAnnotation buddy class in another assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have a project called **Model**. All of my entities are in that project generated by **EF Code** first.

```
Public Partial Class Person
{
    ...
}
```

I don't want to touch my generated classes so I can create a **partial class** and add `MetadataType` attribute to it.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Person_Metadata))]
public partial class Person
{
}
```

And here is my **buddy class**.

```
[Bind(Exclude="PersonID")]
public class Person_Metadata
{
    [Display(Name:="First name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name:="Last name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is, **I want to move my buddy class to another assembly**.

Model project has **no reference to it** so `[MetadataType(typeof(Person_Metadata))]` gives an error because it has no reference to `Person_Metadata` class.

I can use **FluentValidation** for validation part (and it works great), but what about other Metadata like: `Display` Attribute ?

I have also found this question: [Adding DataAnnotation to class when using FluentValidation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810851/adding-dataannotation-to-class-when-using-fluentvalidation) about managing MetaData with FluentValidation engine, but that looks like a long way to go and I prefer using data annotation attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is, I want to move my buddy class to another assembly.

That's impossible. Partial classes work only within the boundaries of the same assembly.

> I can use FluentValidation for validation part (and it works great),
>   but what about other Metadata like: Display Attribute ?

Nothing, they just could stay on your **view model**. Not on your domain model. Your view models are classes that you specifically design to meet the requirements of your views. It's on those view models that you would use the `[DisplayFormat]` and similar attributes.

Comment: Thanks Darin. I have view models in my project and i use automapper with them, but in some parts i want to use my models. I was hoping to find a way like a custom model metadata provider or something like it.

Comment: Normally you should never need to use your models in your views.

Comment: I'm completely on your side with using view models. But do you think such scenario is possible using a custom model metadata provider or not?

Answer (score 2):

I know its too late to reply, but someone may get help from it.

I had similar situation where existing Model classes/Entities were created in an independent assembly and that was also in DotNet 3.5.

I Had to make reuse of the above assembly but this time in ASP.Net MVC 5. For that i figured out that the classes in Model assembly, if marked as public can be inherited in ASP.Net MVC project and there we can add buddy classes for data annotations.

It worked perfectly....

Comment: Thanks a lot man, you saved my day. I'm trying to implement the same inside a Blazor project and my biggest fear was localizing class inside another project and it works as charm now.