# MetadataType without applying attribute on target class?

Tags: c#, .net, metadatatype

Is it possible to apply a `MetadataType` class to a target class without applying a `MetadataType` attribute directly to that class?

Say I've got this class:

```
public class Animal
{
    public int AnimalId { get; set; }
    public string AnimalType { get; set; }
}
```

And this other class:

```
public class AnimalMetadata
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AnimalId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Animal Type must not exceed 100 characters")]
    [Display(Name = "Taxonomical Classification")]
    public string AnimalType { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to apply the `AnimalMetadata` class as the `MetadataType` for `Animal`. But say I don't own the `Animal` class such that I can apply an attribute on it, or it resides in an assembly that cannot be introduced to `AnimalMetadata` and all of its referential dependencies. Can I still use `AnimalMetadata` as a `MetadataType` for `Animal`? If so, how?

Comment: Search custom metadata provider, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810851/adding-dataannotation-to-class-when-using-fluentvalidation

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising.